# Wygwam not loading

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam

Updated EE v2.10.1 and using Wygwam v3.3.3
I have it set to initialize on click, and can see the field and all the content correctly. Clicking on the field makes it completely disappear.

Doesn't appear to be any errors(?).

Thought it may related to Channel Images but it appears the CI plugin for Wygwam is incorporated in the dl.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you also updated the themes folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated Channel Images addon as well? Have you checked your developer console to see your JavaScript errors? It is almost certainly a 404 (like @balloonatic said), a JavaScript conflict, or an un-updated addon in general.

Comment: Thanks very much. Turned out the "Channel Files" plugin was missing.